# using rule engines

Tags: java, rule

I want a rule engine to calculate the truth values of formulas (and/or) + inferring new rules from the current KB.

I searched most of the rule engines but I can not find a concrete example.  Could you please help me with an example?

Comment: consider asking on semanticoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest open source [Drools](http://www.jboss.org/drools) for your requirements. Please take a look at this tutorial: http://www.developer.com/java/ent/article.php/10933_3821101_4/Rev-Up-the-Drools-5-Java-Rule-Engine.htm

Answer (score 0):

Rules and inferencing are big topics in the semantic web world.  You can model an ontology in OWL and run a reasoner over your model and instance data and produce inferred facts.  [The Jena framework](http://jena.sourceforge.net/) has an excellent rules engine with native support plus drop in reasoner support for many of the current semantic web favorites such as Pellet, Racer and FaCT.  See http://jena.sourceforge.net/inference/